# Get the contents of an expanded expression given to eval through Bash internals

Tags: bash

I'm writing some shell functions that allow to print stack traces when errors occur. For this I'm using the `BASH_LINENO` array which contain the line number for each frame. Then I retrieve the line from the file using `BASH_SOURCE` array and a subprocess like `line="$(tail -n+$lineno "$file" | head -n1)"`.

Anyway, it works well, except when an error occur within an `eval`. The problem is that the line number corresponds to the line **after** the expression given to `eval` has been expanded. Therefore, when I retrieve the line with head and tail, obviously it's now the wrong one, or it's not a line at all (lineno is superior to the number of lines in the file).

So I wonder how I could get the actual expanded line. I looked at the variables provided by Bash, but none seems to help in this case.

Example, script1.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "$(./script2.sh)"
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo
echo
echo
echo false
```

When I hit the `false` line when executing `script1.sh`, the line number I get is 4, and the file source I get is `script1.sh`, so it's wrong.

When the line is out of the file, I could detect it, and print the first previous eval line instead, but it's very hacky and I'm sure there are a few different cases to handle. And if the line is within the file, then I cannot even know if it's the right one or not.

`eval` is hell :'(

Ideally, the `BASH_COMMAND` would be an array as well, and I could retrieve the commands from it instead of reading the files.

Another idea I just have would be to force the user to pipe the result of the expression into a command that will compress it on one line. Any ideas how, or programs to do that? A simple join on ";" seems to naive (again, lots of edge cases).

P.S.: sorry for the title, I have difficulty giving a meaningful title to this one :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a workaround: by overriding the `eval` command with my own function, I was able to change the way I print the stack trace for errors happening in `eval` statements.

```
eval() {
    # pre eval logic
    command eval "$@"
    # post eval logic
}
```

Anyway, please don't use `eval`, or if you do, use only one line arguments:

```
# GOOD: "easy" to deal with
for i in ...; do
    eval "$(some command)"
done

# BAD: this will mess up your line numbers
eval "$(for i in ...; do
    some command $i
done)"
```