# Get the list/stack of commands, without using BASH_SOURCE and BASH_LINENO to read them from the executed files

Tags: bash

Just like getting the function calls with `${FUNCNAME[@]}`, is there a way to get the commands? `BASH_COMMAND` can only be used to get the last command (it's not an array, just a string).

I know I can achieve that by using `BASH_SOURCE` and `BASH_LINENO` to read the right line from the right file, but it does not work in case of `eval`s (see my other, less-specific question [Get the contents of an expanded expression given to eval through Bash internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577662/get-the-contents-of-an-expanded-expression-given-to-eval-through-bash-internals))

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: there's no way to do that in Bash.

Related to the linked question and `eval`: Zsh seems to handle `eval`s better, with variables and arrays such as `EVAL_LINENO`, `zsh_eval_context` and others.

> **funcstack**
>   This array contains the names of the functions, sourced files, and (if **EVAL_LINENO** is set) **eval** commands. currently being executed. The first element is the name of the function using the parameter.
>
> The  standard  shell array **zsh_eval_context** can be used to determine the type of shell construct being executed at each depth: note, however, that is in the opposite order, with the most recent item last, and it is more detailed, for example including an entry for **toplevel**, the main shell code being executed either interactively or from a script, which is not present in **$funcstack**.

See `man zshall` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What is your intent? If you want to print a stack trace, you can use the Bash builtin command `caller`, like this:

```
dump_trace() {
    local frame=0 line func source n=0
    while caller "$frame"; do
        ((frame++))
    done | while read line func source; do
        ((n++ == 0)) && {
            printf 'Stack trace:\n'
        }
        printf '%4s at %s\n' " " "$func ($source:$line)"
    done
}
```

---

From Bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html):

> caller [expr]
>
> Returns the context of any active subroutine call (a shell function or
>   a script executed with the . or source builtins).
>
> Without expr, caller displays the line number and source filename of
>   the current subroutine call. If a non-negative integer is supplied as
>   expr, caller displays the line number, subroutine name, and source
>   file corresponding to that position in the current execution call
>   stack. This extra information may be used, for example, to print a
>   stack trace. The current frame is frame 0.
>
> The return value is 0 unless the shell is not executing a subroutine
>   call or expr does not correspond to a valid position in the call
>   stack.

---

See the full logging/error handling implementation here:

https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Comment: My intent is to print a stack trace indeed :) But I find them only useful **with the actual line of code** that caused an error (I print the stacktrace with a trap on ERR). The problem is that, to get the actual line of code, I have to read the file, and when an eval was used, the line number is increased, so it messes up (wrong line / no line). I also cannot reliably tell if an eval was used or if the line is incorrect. This is yet another limitation of eval I guess. I'm gonna stop using it anyway.